# How to import pandas and matplotlib on Python 3.5 IDLE

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-idle

I am running the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')

web_stats = {"Day":[1,2,3,4,5,6],
            "Visitors":[43,53,34,45,64,34],
            "Bounce_Rate":[65,72,62,64,54,66]}
df = pd.DataFrame(web_stats)
print(df)
```

It works just fine for me in the Jupyter notebook. But I am getting errors when I try to run it on IDLE, and I am wondering how to make it work there, too.

Here are the errors I'm getting:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\theca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\pandas.py", line 1, in 
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\theca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\pandas.py", line 2, in 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'

I am new to Python, please to help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you actually installed pandas and matplotlib?

Your best bet would be to install [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), which automatically installs some useful Python libraries for you.

If you don't want to install so many unnecessary libraries, you can install pandas via pip: `pip install pandas`, and matplotlib by `pip install matplotlib`. If you use pip you may have to install dependencies, so up to you.

EDIT: Your paths may also be setup wrongly. Check if the libraries are installed under the correct folder, `C:\Users\theca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\pandas.py`, for example here. If not, you either have to move them or setup the path in python, like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("<the install path here>")
import pandas
```

Comment: I have Anaconda, and I did pip install on those things. I open up the Jupyter notebook in a browser and it works fine.

Comment: I want it to work on IDLE Python, as well, but I think IDLE is not finding them.

Comment: @Jabernet Did the libraries get installed on Python 2.x instead by accident?

Comment: I'll have to figure that out if I can, as far as I know all I have is Python 3.5 and dependencies and packages for Python 3.5.

Comment: @Jabernet check the edit, your paths may be set up wrongly as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate of similar questions.  The question is not really about IDLE, but about having multiple versions of python installed, or the same version installed more than once.  The answer is that you have to install packages for each python executable that you want to use them with.

You traceback says that you ran IDLE with "C:\Users\theca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32" and that pandas is installed with it, started to run, tried to import matlib.pyplot as plt, and failed.  You need to install matlib with the same python.  Try

```
C:\Users\theca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32 -m pip install matlib
```

Comment: C:\Users\theca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32>pip install matplotlib

I put it here, and it attempts to do it in the Anaconda folder anyway, and I get "requirement already satisfied". Still won't run on my IDLE.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem : it is indeed a problem of having different versions of python installed. If your Idle is working with python 3.5, then you just have to do

> pip3.5 install matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you used `Anaconda` to install `pandas` and `matplotlib`. Thus, these two modules are installed only in **Anaconda virtual environments**. The Python IDLE cannot find modules in virtual env, it only search modules located in system paths.

So, you need to reinstall these modules in Windows `cmd` rather than `Anaconda` if you insist to use Python IDLE.

```
1. win + r
2. input cmd
3. pip install pandas, matplotlib
```

In all, I recommend to use `Anaconda` and the IDE in it named `Spyder`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if you don't have matplotlib installed on your system.
Go to the command prompt and type the following (if you are using windows)-

```
py -m pip install matplotlib
py -m pip install pandas
```

Then try the your code again.

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
try:
    import Pandas as pd
except ImportError as e:
     e = str(e)[15:]
     e = e.strip().replace("'", "")
     os.system('py -m pip install %s' % (e))
```

Try above code. In window cmd you have to type py and they python code or module to run it from cmd.

Answer (score -1):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

web_stats = {"Day":[1,2,3,4,5,6],
            "Visitors":[43,53,34,45,64,34],
            "Bounce_Rate":[65,72,62,64,54,66]}
df = pd.DataFrame(web_stats)
df.plot(grid=True)
plt.show()
```

You can try above code. It works.

Answer (score -1):

**Installing Python Pandas on Windows With pip:**

1- you should head over to our **terminal or command prompt** from where you can install Pandas. **So go to your search bar on your desktop and search for cmd**. An application called Command prompt should show up

2-  and **immediately** **Type** in the **command** **"pip install pandas"**. Pip is a package install manager for Python and Wait for the downloads to be over and once

3- you can **type** "**import pandas as pd**" in **IDLE**

4- and congratulations! you have pandas and other lib with this way:).